# Is there an IndexSet and a Range class for Java?

Tags: java, cocoa, range, indexing

In Objective-C Cocoa we have the `NSIndexSet` class which stores a series of unique indexes efficiently by keeping an array of ranges. E.g. the set 1, 2, ... 30, 57 would be stored as the ranges 1-30 and 57 rather than an array of 32 numbers. This facilitates huge selections to be stored in a simple and fast way. For example, if all rows between 1 and a million in a table selected, the index set collapses to just a tiny range and is fast to compare and intersect with.

Unfortunately this turns out to be rather hard to Google for. Is there an equivalent class for Java?

Comment: Check out BitSet class. Is not exacly Range as you expressed here but it might do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a useful class, and I don't recall a standard implementation.

Here's a bunch of some -perhaps useful- pointers.

[A range intersection algorithm better than O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303591/a-range-intersection-algorithm-better-than-on)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/rangeset.aspx

http://healpix-rangeset.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/healpix-rangeset/src/org/asterope/healpix/LongRangeSet.java

http://pcj.sourceforge.net/docs/api/bak/pcj/set/IntRangeSet.html

[Data structure to build and lookup set of integer ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601749/data-structure-to-build-and-lookup-set-of-integer-ranges)

[Representing sparse integer sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361040/representing-sparse-integer-sets)

http://www.iis.uni-stuttgart.de/intset/doc/intset/TreeIntegerSet.html

Comment: IntRangeSet from PCJ seems to fit the bill. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is the Apache commons [IntRange](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/IntRange.html)

Comment: Actually there are also other types of ranges http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang/math/Range.html

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not last and not least, there is a [Range class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) in the Guava library. This [article](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained) does a nice job of illustrating how you might use it.